# How to change name of jfxsa-run

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, netbeans-8

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTu3O.png)

How do I go about changing this? The output says a name nowhere near any of the file names/project names I have. I've been searching around Netbeans how to change it but can't find anything. Is there a way to manually change this name?

Using Netbeans 8.0.2

Thank you

Comment: Im referring to changing the name of the jfxsa-run. Currently says: AlmirMuratovicC482, just want to change to testing

Comment: Solved: It is in the build file